# What does "history_node table is full" error in cadence-history service mean?

Tags: mysql, cadence-workflow

we are seeing cadence-history server `The table 'history_node' is full` errors in our logs. We're on version 0.16.0 and using MySql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you are using Cadence with MySQL and the MySQL host is running out of disk capacity. Adding more storage capacity to your database should resolve the issue.

Comment: Increasing storage on MySql helped resolve this issue. Thanks!